# FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/app/log4net.config'. in asp.net core while running in docker conainer although it is running in localhost

Tags: asp.net, docker, .net-core, containers, log4net

I have asp.net core application with log4net enabled and it is running fine in localhost
after creating docker image then i tried to run it is throwing error below

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[6]
      Application startup exception
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/app/log4net.config'.
File name: '/app/log4net.config'
   at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
   at System.IO.FileStream.OpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.IO.File.OpenRead(String path)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4NetProvider.ParseLog4NetConfigFile(String filename)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4NetProvider.ConfigureLog4NetLibrary(Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4NetProvider..ctor(Log4NetProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4NetExtensions.AddLog4Net(ILoggerFactory factory, Log4NetProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4NetExtensions.AddLog4Net(ILoggerFactory factory)
   at dockertesting3log.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in /src/dockertesting3log/Startup.cs:line 46
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/app/log4net.config'.
File name: '/app/log4net.config'
   at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
   at System.IO.FileStream.OpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.IO.File.OpenRead(String path)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4NetProvider.ParseLog4NetConfigFile(String filename)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4NetProvider.ConfigureLog4NetLibrary(Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4NetProvider..ctor(Log4NetProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4NetExtensions.AddLog4Net(ILoggerFactory factory, Log4NetProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4NetExtensions.AddLog4Net(ILoggerFactory factory)
   at dockertesting3log.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in /src/dockertesting3log/Startup.cs:line 46
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at dockertesting3log.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/dockertesting3log/Program.cs:line 18
```

I have also checked the image content log4net.dll is present in image.
[attached the image for the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiSmd.png)

Here is the dockerfile which i am using to create docker image

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["dockertesting3log/dockertesting3log.csproj", "dockertesting3log/"]
RUN dotnet restore "dockertesting3log/dockertesting3log.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/dockertesting3log"
RUN dotnet build "dockertesting3log.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "dockertesting3log.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dockertesting3log.dll"]
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the log4net.config file as Copy Always / Copy if newer from Visual Studio?

Comment: yes I tried it is working in visual studio but not working while running image in docker container

Comment: Did you try to bash into the container and see if the file is present at the correct location?
`docker exec -it <container_id/name> bash`

Comment: I tried to dive in image using docker dive tool and also attach image content in question,but not able to run the container,so how i can `docker exec`.it is throwing error in the first place.Error i had already quoted in the posted above question.

Comment: got the error I have created log4Net.config file in source code and docker build command copying it by same name log4Net.config ,but the correct way to use log4net.config is use it with all smallcase letters `log4net.config`.Thanks all for your comments, able to learn new things.

Comment: If the container isn't starting write multiple `RUN` commands for the folders you expect to have the `config` file. e.g.
`RUN ls /app` (`WORKDIR` path is going to affect command output)

Comment: Also if the container isn't starting change your `ENTERYPOINT` command to 
`ENTERYPOINT ["bash"]`

Comment: You copy from `publish` and `base` parts. But you copy your files in `build` part.